# R: Indexing Sublists

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

This is my first time asking a question.
I have 60 different lists in R, all containing the same indices (e.g.: Price, Return, etc.).  I would like to combine all of the into one list to call a sublist from each of them.  For example, two of my lists are BXUB and BXUC.  If I call BXUB$Price or BXUC$Price, I get all of the prices I am looking for.  However, I have tried combining the lists into a "total" list using as.list, list, cbind, etc.  The goal being that if I call Total$Price, I get a list of BXUB Price and BXUC Price.  Right now I only get the Price for the first entry.  Thank you for the help. For example:

```
total<-as.list(BXUB, BXUC) #only provides the prices for BXUB when I call total$Price

BXUB
$Price
                       Price
2013-07-31 16:15:00 144.6200
2013-08-01 14:05:00 146.0199
2013-08-01 16:15:00 146.0199
2013-08-07 14:04:00 143.9201
2013-08-07 16:15:00 143.9201
2013-08-12 10:52:00 143.8600
2013-08-12 16:15:00 143.8600
2013-08-19 09:30:00 140.0000
2013-08-19 16:15:00 140.0000
2013-09-04 10:16:00 138.1286
2013-09-04 10:45:00 138.1100
2013-09-04 16:15:00 138.1100
2013-09-10 11:53:00 142.7780
2013-09-10 16:15:00 142.7780
2013-09-12 10:41:00 144.3210
2013-09-12 16:15:00 144.3210
2013-09-17 11:07:00 146.4100
2013-09-17 16:15:00 146.4100
2013-09-19 09:39:00 149.9771
2013-09-19 16:15:00 149.9771
2013-09-23 10:42:00 146.2210
2013-09-23 16:15:00 146.2210
2013-09-24 12:52:00 146.7320
2013-09-24 16:15:00 146.7320
2013-09-30 15:01:00 143.6000
2013-09-30 15:02:00 143.3400
2013-09-30 16:15:00 143.3400
2013-10-07 15:10:00 143.6101
2013-10-07 16:15:00 143.6101
2013-10-08 15:07:00 140.2500
2013-10-08 15:22:00 140.4900
2013-10-08 16:15:00 140.4900
2013-10-10 11:29:00 143.2350
2013-10-10 16:15:00 143.2350
2013-10-16 09:56:00 148.0000
2013-10-16 10:52:00 148.8300
2013-10-16 13:20:00 148.8400
2013-10-16 16:15:00 148.8400
2013-10-22 09:30:00 153.0000
2013-10-22 16:15:00 153.0000
2013-10-25 10:00:00 154.7600
2013-10-25 16:15:00 154.7600
2013-10-29 10:07:00 155.6901
2013-10-29 10:49:00 155.9580
2013-10-29 16:15:00 155.9580
2013-10-30 10:20:00 156.5900
2013-10-30 10:59:00 156.8000
2013-10-30 16:15:00 156.8000
2013-10-31 12:04:00 155.3300
2013-10-31 16:15:00 155.3300
2013-11-06 10:28:00 156.6700
2013-11-06 16:15:00 156.6700
2013-11-13 12:44:00 157.0400
2013-11-13 16:15:00 157.0400
2013-11-18 09:47:00 161.1100
2013-11-18 16:15:00 161.1100
2013-11-25 15:44:00 161.6600
2013-11-25 16:15:00 161.6600
2013-11-26 10:18:00 161.9599
2013-11-26 14:16:00 162.3700
2013-11-26 16:15:00 162.3700
2013-11-29 11:05:00 163.2400
2013-11-29 13:40:00 163.2400
2013-11-29 16:15:00 163.2400
2013-12-02 15:58:00 161.2700
2013-12-02 16:15:00 161.2700
2013-12-06 09:35:00 161.7700
2013-12-06 11:53:00 161.8600
2013-12-06 16:15:00 161.8600
2013-12-09 16:15:00 161.8600
2013-12-10 16:15:00 161.8600
2013-12-11 16:15:00 161.8600
2013-12-12 16:15:00 161.8600
2013-12-13 14:05:00 158.0401
2013-12-13 16:15:00 158.0401
2013-12-16 16:15:00 158.0401
2013-12-17 09:51:00 158.9700
2013-12-17 16:15:00 158.9700
2013-12-18 16:15:00 158.9700
2013-12-19 16:15:00 158.9700
2013-12-20 14:20:00 165.0000
2013-12-20 16:15:00 165.0000
2013-12-23 09:45:00 165.9800
2013-12-23 13:52:00 165.6000
2013-12-23 16:15:00 165.6000
2013-12-26 10:40:00 167.4500
2013-12-26 16:15:00 167.4500
2013-12-27 16:15:00 167.4500
2013-12-31 11:23:00 168.9000
2013-12-31 11:34:00 168.8900
2013-12-31 16:15:00 168.8900
2014-01-03 10:13:00 167.3000
2014-01-03 13:17:00 166.5100
2014-01-03 13:18:00 166.3700
2014-01-03 16:15:00 166.3700
2014-01-06 09:30:00 165.5000
2014-01-06 09:31:00 167.2600
2014-01-06 09:38:00 167.0200
2014-01-06 16:15:00 167.0200
2014-01-07 16:15:00 167.0200
2014-01-08 16:15:00 167.0200
2014-01-13 16:15:00 167.0200
2014-01-15 10:32:00 169.1010
2014-01-15 16:15:00 169.1010
2014-01-16 16:15:00 169.1010
2014-01-17 11:26:00 168.5380
2014-01-17 15:45:00 167.3700
2014-01-17 16:15:00 167.3700
2014-01-21 16:15:00 167.3700
2014-01-22 16:15:00 167.3700
2014-01-23 16:15:00 167.3700
2014-01-27 10:33:00 159.8600
2014-01-27 16:15:00 159.8600
2014-01-30 16:15:00 159.8600
2014-01-31 15:42:00 159.8900
2014-01-31 16:15:00 159.8900
2014-02-03 13:45:00 154.2500
2014-02-03 16:15:00 154.2500
2014-02-04 16:15:00 154.2500
2014-02-05 13:02:00 155.0500
2014-02-05 16:15:00 155.0500
2014-02-06 15:38:00 158.1100
2014-02-06 16:15:00 158.1100

$Return
                           Return
2013-07-31 16:15:00  9.633301e-03
2013-08-01 14:05:00  0.000000e+00
2013-08-01 16:15:00 -1.448463e-02
2013-08-07 14:04:00  0.000000e+00
2013-08-07 16:15:00 -4.176800e-04
2013-08-12 10:52:00  0.000000e+00
2013-08-12 16:15:00 -2.719818e-02
2013-08-19 09:30:00  0.000000e+00
2013-08-19 16:15:00 -1.345729e-02
2013-09-04 10:16:00 -1.346662e-04
2013-09-04 10:45:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-04 16:15:00  3.324051e-02
2013-09-10 11:53:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-10 16:15:00  1.074901e-02
2013-09-12 10:41:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-12 16:15:00  1.437092e-02
2013-09-17 11:07:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-17 16:15:00  2.407171e-02
2013-09-19 09:39:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-19 16:15:00 -2.536344e-02
2013-09-23 10:42:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-23 16:15:00  3.488618e-03
2013-09-24 12:52:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-24 16:15:00 -2.157614e-02
2013-09-30 15:01:00 -1.812226e-03
2013-09-30 15:02:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-30 16:15:00  1.882558e-03
2013-10-07 15:10:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-07 16:15:00 -2.367544e-02
2013-10-08 15:07:00  1.709767e-03
2013-10-08 15:22:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-08 16:15:00  1.935033e-02
2013-10-10 11:29:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-10 16:15:00  3.272564e-02
2013-10-16 09:56:00  5.592441e-03
2013-10-16 10:52:00  6.718850e-05
2013-10-16 13:20:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-16 16:15:00  2.756602e-02
2013-10-22 09:30:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-22 16:15:00  1.143761e-02
2013-10-25 10:00:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-25 16:15:00  5.991963e-03
2013-10-29 10:07:00  1.719247e-03
2013-10-29 10:49:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-29 16:15:00  4.044184e-03
2013-10-30 10:20:00  1.340183e-03
2013-10-30 10:59:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-30 16:15:00 -9.419222e-03
2013-10-31 12:04:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-31 16:15:00  8.589796e-03
2013-11-06 10:28:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-06 16:15:00  2.358868e-03
2013-11-13 12:44:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-13 16:15:00  2.558681e-02
2013-11-18 09:47:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-18 16:15:00  3.408003e-03
2013-11-25 15:44:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-25 16:15:00  1.853409e-03
2013-11-26 10:18:00  2.528908e-03
2013-11-26 14:16:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-26 16:15:00  5.343829e-03
2013-11-29 11:05:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-29 13:40:00  0.000000e+00
2013-11-29 16:15:00 -1.214153e-02
2013-12-02 15:58:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-02 16:15:00  3.095594e-03
2013-12-06 09:35:00  5.561907e-04
2013-12-06 11:53:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-06 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-09 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-10 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-11 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-12 16:15:00 -2.388297e-02
2013-12-13 14:05:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-13 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-16 16:15:00  5.866707e-03
2013-12-17 09:51:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-17 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-18 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-19 16:15:00  3.722997e-02
2013-12-20 14:20:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-20 16:15:00  5.921825e-03
2013-12-23 09:45:00 -2.292057e-03
2013-12-23 13:52:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-23 16:15:00  1.110956e-02
2013-12-26 10:40:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-26 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-27 16:15:00  8.622025e-03
2013-12-31 11:23:00 -5.920838e-05
2013-12-31 11:34:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-31 16:15:00 -9.459007e-03
2014-01-03 10:13:00 -4.733240e-03
2014-01-03 13:17:00 -8.411440e-04
2014-01-03 13:18:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-03 16:15:00 -5.243029e-03
2014-01-06 09:30:00  1.057829e-02
2014-01-06 09:31:00 -1.435922e-03
2014-01-06 09:38:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-06 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-07 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-08 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-13 16:15:00  1.238260e-02
2014-01-15 10:32:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-15 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-16 16:15:00 -3.334926e-03
2014-01-17 11:26:00 -6.954313e-03
2014-01-17 15:45:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-17 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-21 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-22 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-23 16:15:00 -4.590850e-02
2014-01-27 10:33:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-27 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-30 16:15:00  1.876466e-04
2014-01-31 15:42:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-31 16:15:00 -3.591142e-02
2014-02-03 13:45:00  0.000000e+00
2014-02-03 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-02-04 16:15:00  5.172983e-03
2014-02-05 13:02:00  0.000000e+00
2014-02-05 16:15:00  1.954335e-02
2014-02-06 15:38:00  0.000000e+00
2014-02-06 16:15:00            NA

$`Std Dev, Daily`
                    Std Dev, Daily
2013-07-31 16:15:00             NA
2013-08-01 14:05:00             NA
2013-08-01 16:15:00   0.0102421801
2013-08-07 14:04:00             NA
2013-08-07 16:15:00   0.0002953444
2013-08-12 10:52:00             NA
2013-08-12 16:15:00   0.0192320175
2013-08-19 09:30:00             NA
2013-08-19 16:15:00   0.0095157410
2013-09-04 10:16:00             NA
2013-09-04 10:45:00             NA
2013-09-04 16:15:00   0.0192304101
2013-09-10 11:53:00             NA
2013-09-10 16:15:00   0.0076006979
2013-09-12 10:41:00             NA
2013-09-12 16:15:00   0.0101617750
2013-09-17 11:07:00             NA
2013-09-17 16:15:00   0.0170212694
2013-09-19 09:39:00             NA
2013-09-19 16:15:00   0.0179346604
2013-09-23 10:42:00             NA
2013-09-23 16:15:00   0.0024668254
2013-09-24 12:52:00             NA
2013-09-24 16:15:00   0.0152566349
2013-09-30 15:01:00             NA
2013-09-30 15:02:00             NA
2013-09-30 16:15:00   0.0018475036
2013-10-07 15:10:00             NA
2013-10-07 16:15:00   0.0167410642
2013-10-08 15:07:00             NA
2013-10-08 15:22:00             NA
2013-10-08 16:15:00   0.0107125163
2013-10-10 11:29:00             NA
2013-10-10 16:15:00   0.0231405220
2013-10-16 09:56:00             NA
2013-10-16 10:52:00             NA
2013-10-16 13:20:00             NA
2013-10-16 16:15:00   0.0131044448
2013-10-22 09:30:00             NA
2013-10-22 16:15:00   0.0080876116
2013-10-25 10:00:00             NA
2013-10-25 16:15:00   0.0042369577
2013-10-29 10:07:00             NA
2013-10-29 10:49:00             NA
2013-10-29 16:15:00   0.0020296373
2013-10-30 10:20:00             NA
2013-10-30 10:59:00             NA
2013-10-30 16:15:00   0.0058634835
2013-10-31 12:04:00             NA
2013-10-31 16:15:00   0.0060739030
2013-11-06 10:28:00             NA
2013-11-06 16:15:00   0.0016679716
2013-11-13 12:44:00             NA
2013-11-13 16:15:00   0.0180926069
2013-11-18 09:47:00             NA
2013-11-18 16:15:00   0.0024098220
2013-11-25 15:44:00             NA
2013-11-25 16:15:00   0.0013105581
2013-11-26 10:18:00             NA
2013-11-26 14:16:00             NA
2013-11-26 16:15:00   0.0026731899
2013-11-29 11:05:00             NA
2013-11-29 13:40:00             NA
2013-11-29 16:15:00   0.0070099156
2013-12-02 15:58:00             NA
2013-12-02 16:15:00   0.0021889155
2013-12-06 09:35:00             NA
2013-12-06 11:53:00             NA
2013-12-06 16:15:00   0.0003211169
2013-12-09 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-10 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-11 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-12 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-13 14:05:00             NA
2013-12-13 16:15:00   0.0000000000
2013-12-16 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-17 09:51:00             NA
2013-12-17 16:15:00   0.0000000000
2013-12-18 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-19 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-20 14:20:00             NA
2013-12-20 16:15:00   0.0041873626
2013-12-23 09:45:00             NA
2013-12-23 13:52:00             NA
2013-12-23 16:15:00   0.0071679749
2013-12-26 10:40:00             NA
2013-12-26 16:15:00   0.0000000000
2013-12-27 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-31 11:23:00             NA
2013-12-31 11:34:00             NA
2013-12-31 16:15:00   0.0054441487
2014-01-03 10:13:00             NA
2014-01-03 13:17:00             NA
2014-01-03 13:18:00             NA
2014-01-03 16:15:00   0.0026674789
2014-01-06 09:30:00             NA
2014-01-06 09:31:00             NA
2014-01-06 09:38:00             NA
2014-01-06 16:15:00   0.0055697507
2014-01-07 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-08 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-13 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-15 10:32:00             NA
2014-01-15 16:15:00   0.0000000000
2014-01-16 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-17 11:26:00             NA
2014-01-17 15:45:00             NA
2014-01-17 16:15:00   0.0040150745
2014-01-21 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-22 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-23 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-27 10:33:00             NA
2014-01-27 16:15:00   0.0000000000
2014-01-30 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-31 15:42:00             NA
2014-01-31 16:15:00   0.0253932086
2014-02-03 13:45:00             NA
2014-02-03 16:15:00   0.0000000000
2014-02-04 16:15:00             NA
2014-02-05 13:02:00             NA
2014-02-05 16:15:00   0.0138192353
2014-02-06 15:38:00             NA
2014-02-06 16:15:00             NA

$`Std Dev, Weekly`
                    Std Dev, Weekly
2013-07-31 16:15:00              NA
2013-08-01 14:05:00              NA
2013-08-01 16:15:00    0.0121400137
2013-08-07 14:04:00              NA
2013-08-07 16:15:00    0.0002953444
2013-08-12 10:52:00              NA
2013-08-12 16:15:00    0.0192320175
2013-08-19 09:30:00              NA
2013-08-19 16:15:00    0.0095157410
2013-09-04 10:16:00              NA
2013-09-04 10:45:00              NA
2013-09-04 16:15:00    0.0192304101
2013-09-10 11:53:00              NA
2013-09-10 16:15:00              NA
2013-09-12 10:41:00              NA
2013-09-12 16:15:00    0.0074007170
2013-09-17 11:07:00              NA
2013-09-17 16:15:00              NA
2013-09-19 09:39:00              NA
2013-09-19 16:15:00    0.0201852600
2013-09-23 10:42:00              NA
2013-09-23 16:15:00              NA
2013-09-24 12:52:00              NA
2013-09-24 16:15:00    0.0114878292
2013-09-30 15:01:00              NA
2013-09-30 15:02:00              NA
2013-09-30 16:15:00    0.0018475036
2013-10-07 15:10:00              NA
2013-10-07 16:15:00              NA
2013-10-08 15:07:00              NA
2013-10-08 15:22:00              NA
2013-10-08 16:15:00              NA
2013-10-10 11:29:00              NA
2013-10-10 16:15:00    0.0176980883
2013-10-16 09:56:00              NA
2013-10-16 10:52:00              NA
2013-10-16 13:20:00              NA
2013-10-16 16:15:00    0.0131044448
2013-10-22 09:30:00              NA
2013-10-22 16:15:00              NA
2013-10-25 10:00:00              NA
2013-10-25 16:15:00    0.0055007587
2013-10-29 10:07:00              NA
2013-10-29 10:49:00              NA
2013-10-29 16:15:00              NA
2013-10-30 10:20:00              NA
2013-10-30 10:59:00              NA
2013-10-30 16:15:00              NA
2013-10-31 12:04:00              NA
2013-10-31 16:15:00    0.0050524815
2013-11-06 10:28:00              NA
2013-11-06 16:15:00    0.0016679716
2013-11-13 12:44:00              NA
2013-11-13 16:15:00    0.0180926069
2013-11-18 09:47:00              NA
2013-11-18 16:15:00    0.0024098220
2013-11-25 15:44:00              NA
2013-11-25 16:15:00              NA
2013-11-26 10:18:00              NA
2013-11-26 14:16:00              NA
2013-11-26 16:15:00              NA
2013-11-29 11:05:00              NA
2013-11-29 13:40:00              NA
2013-11-29 16:15:00    0.0051419076
2013-12-02 15:58:00              NA
2013-12-02 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-06 09:35:00              NA
2013-12-06 11:53:00              NA
2013-12-06 16:15:00    0.0013439628
2013-12-09 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-10 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-11 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-12 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-13 14:05:00              NA
2013-12-13 16:15:00    0.0097501817
2013-12-16 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-17 09:51:00              NA
2013-12-17 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-18 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-19 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-20 14:20:00              NA
2013-12-20 16:15:00    0.0136155417
2013-12-23 09:45:00              NA
2013-12-23 13:52:00              NA
2013-12-23 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-26 10:40:00              NA
2013-12-26 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-27 16:15:00    0.0055195225
2013-12-31 11:23:00              NA
2013-12-31 11:34:00              NA
2013-12-31 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-03 10:13:00              NA
2014-01-03 13:17:00              NA
2014-01-03 13:18:00              NA
2014-01-03 16:15:00    0.0036742330
2014-01-06 09:30:00              NA
2014-01-06 09:31:00              NA
2014-01-06 09:38:00              NA
2014-01-06 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-07 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-08 16:15:00    0.0044728427
2014-01-13 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-15 10:32:00              NA
2014-01-15 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-16 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-17 11:26:00              NA
2014-01-17 15:45:00              NA
2014-01-17 16:15:00    0.0059468053
2014-01-21 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-22 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-23 16:15:00    0.0265052848
2014-01-27 10:33:00              NA
2014-01-27 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-30 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-31 15:42:00              NA
2014-01-31 16:15:00    0.0160812601
2014-02-03 13:45:00              NA
2014-02-03 16:15:00              NA
2014-02-04 16:15:00              NA
2014-02-05 13:02:00              NA
2014-02-05 16:15:00              NA
2014-02-06 15:38:00              NA
2014-02-06 16:15:00              NA

> BXUC
$Price
                      Price
2013-08-09 16:15:00 226.490
2013-09-06 13:50:00 221.670
2013-09-06 13:51:00 221.610
2013-09-06 16:15:00 221.610
2013-09-25 13:50:00 227.730
2013-09-25 16:15:00 227.730
2013-10-07 14:06:00 226.020
2013-10-07 16:15:00 226.020
2013-12-09 16:15:00 226.020
2013-12-13 09:35:00 246.020
2013-12-13 09:36:00 246.230
2013-12-13 10:09:00 245.510
2013-12-13 10:14:00 245.330
2013-12-13 16:15:00 245.330
2013-12-16 16:15:00 245.330
2013-12-18 14:10:00 249.110
2013-12-18 16:15:00 249.110
2013-12-19 16:15:00 249.110
2013-12-20 16:15:00 249.110
2013-12-23 09:43:00 255.810
2013-12-23 16:15:00 255.810
2013-12-24 13:40:00 255.810
2013-12-24 16:15:00 255.810
2013-12-26 12:58:00 258.170
2013-12-26 12:59:00 258.110
2013-12-26 16:15:00 258.110
2013-12-30 11:15:00 258.468
2013-12-30 16:15:00 258.468
2014-01-02 16:15:00 258.468
2014-01-07 16:15:00 258.468
2014-01-08 11:34:00 257.910
2014-01-08 16:15:00 257.910
2014-01-15 16:15:00 257.910
2014-01-17 15:40:00 257.560
2014-01-17 16:15:00 257.560
2014-01-22 12:06:00 258.928
2014-01-22 13:47:00 259.312
2014-01-22 16:15:00 259.312
2014-01-24 16:15:00 259.312
2014-01-27 10:35:00 247.258
2014-01-27 10:42:00 247.270
2014-01-27 16:15:00 247.270
2014-01-28 16:15:00 247.270
2014-01-30 16:15:00 247.270
2014-02-03 16:15:00 247.270
2014-02-06 16:15:00 247.270

$Return
                           Return
2013-08-09 16:15:00 -2.151100e-02
2013-09-06 13:50:00 -2.707093e-04
2013-09-06 13:51:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-06 16:15:00  2.724164e-02
2013-09-25 13:50:00  0.000000e+00
2013-09-25 16:15:00 -7.537226e-03
2013-10-07 14:06:00  0.000000e+00
2013-10-07 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-09 16:15:00  8.478934e-02
2013-12-13 09:35:00  8.532250e-04
2013-12-13 09:36:00 -2.928379e-03
2013-12-13 10:09:00 -7.334366e-04
2013-12-13 10:14:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-13 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-16 16:15:00  1.529032e-02
2013-12-18 14:10:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-18 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-19 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-20 16:15:00  2.654042e-02
2013-12-23 09:43:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-23 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-24 13:40:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-24 16:15:00  9.183301e-03
2013-12-26 12:58:00 -2.324320e-04
2013-12-26 12:59:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-26 16:15:00  1.386045e-03
2013-12-30 11:15:00  0.000000e+00
2013-12-30 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-02 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-07 16:15:00 -2.161208e-03
2014-01-08 11:34:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-08 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-15 16:15:00 -1.357984e-03
2014-01-17 15:40:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-17 16:15:00  5.297328e-03
2014-01-22 12:06:00  1.481939e-03
2014-01-22 13:47:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-22 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-24 16:15:00 -4.759964e-02
2014-01-27 10:35:00  4.853112e-05
2014-01-27 10:42:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-27 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-28 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-01-30 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-02-03 16:15:00  0.000000e+00
2014-02-06 16:15:00            NA

$`Std Dev, Daily`
                    Std Dev, Daily
2013-08-09 16:15:00             NA
2013-09-06 13:50:00             NA
2013-09-06 13:51:00             NA
2013-09-06 16:15:00   1.580669e-02
2013-09-25 13:50:00             NA
2013-09-25 16:15:00   5.329624e-03
2013-10-07 14:06:00             NA
2013-10-07 16:15:00   0.000000e+00
2013-12-09 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-13 09:35:00             NA
2013-12-13 09:36:00             NA
2013-12-13 10:09:00             NA
2013-12-13 10:14:00             NA
2013-12-13 16:15:00   1.437332e-03
2013-12-16 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-18 14:10:00             NA
2013-12-18 16:15:00   0.000000e+00
2013-12-19 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-20 16:15:00             NA
2013-12-23 09:43:00             NA
2013-12-23 16:15:00   0.000000e+00
2013-12-24 13:40:00             NA
2013-12-24 16:15:00   6.493574e-03
2013-12-26 12:58:00             NA
2013-12-26 12:59:00             NA
2013-12-26 16:15:00   8.750822e-04
2013-12-30 11:15:00             NA
2013-12-30 16:15:00   0.000000e+00
2014-01-02 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-07 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-08 11:34:00             NA
2014-01-08 16:15:00   0.000000e+00
2014-01-15 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-17 15:40:00             NA
2014-01-17 16:15:00   3.745777e-03
2014-01-22 12:06:00             NA
2014-01-22 13:47:00             NA
2014-01-22 16:15:00   8.555979e-04
2014-01-24 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-27 10:35:00             NA
2014-01-27 10:42:00             NA
2014-01-27 16:15:00   2.801946e-05
2014-01-28 16:15:00             NA
2014-01-30 16:15:00             NA
2014-02-03 16:15:00             NA
2014-02-06 16:15:00             NA

$`Std Dev, Weekly`
                    Std Dev, Weekly
2013-08-09 16:15:00              NA
2013-09-06 13:50:00              NA
2013-09-06 13:51:00              NA
2013-09-06 16:15:00    1.580669e-02
2013-09-25 13:50:00              NA
2013-09-25 16:15:00    5.329624e-03
2013-10-07 14:06:00              NA
2013-10-07 16:15:00    0.000000e+00
2013-12-09 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-13 09:35:00              NA
2013-12-13 09:36:00              NA
2013-12-13 10:09:00              NA
2013-12-13 10:14:00              NA
2013-12-13 16:15:00    3.486813e-02
2013-12-16 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-18 14:10:00              NA
2013-12-18 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-19 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-20 16:15:00    1.212668e-02
2013-12-23 09:43:00              NA
2013-12-23 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-24 13:40:00              NA
2013-12-24 16:15:00              NA
2013-12-26 12:58:00              NA
2013-12-26 12:59:00              NA
2013-12-26 16:15:00    3.441018e-03
2013-12-30 11:15:00              NA
2013-12-30 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-02 16:15:00    0.000000e+00
2014-01-07 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-08 11:34:00              NA
2014-01-08 16:15:00    1.247774e-03
2014-01-15 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-17 15:40:00              NA
2014-01-17 16:15:00    3.516603e-03
2014-01-22 12:06:00              NA
2014-01-22 13:47:00              NA
2014-01-22 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-24 16:15:00    2.405696e-02
2014-01-27 10:35:00              NA
2014-01-27 10:42:00              NA
2014-01-27 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-28 16:15:00              NA
2014-01-30 16:15:00    2.170378e-05
2014-02-03 16:15:00              NA
2014-02-06 16:15:00              NA

t$Price
                       Price
2013-07-31 16:15:00 144.6200
```

#The list of t$Price continues, just ran out of room. It contains all the $Price data for the first fund.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When asking a question, it's always best to provide a reproducible example (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for tips on how to do this). For example, write to create a sample `SSO` and `SPY` list that we can copy and paste and test any potential solutions with.

Comment: Thanks!  Just updated it.

Comment: Is there any benefit for you to have these date in a list form? Creating a data frame would be more applicable with your `$` operator.

Comment: @user3731327 You updated the question with the results of a failed attempt at combining two lists. you didn't show what the original lists looked like nor what you expected the output to be. While it's always nice to share code you've tried, this is probably the least helpful portion of your code you could have shared. Again, focus on the input and desired output. Feel free to reduce the number of elements in the list when posting. There is no reason we need to see 123 records when just seeing 10 gives the same information.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the variables are in the same order n each list

```
# Create two lists of values - simplified from your data
sso <- list(price=c(50,50,50), return=20, other="a")
spy <- list(price=c(30,30), return=c(10,10) , other="g")

# Combine    
total <- mapply(list, sso, spy, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)    
total <- lapply(total, function(i) setNames(i, c("sso", "spy")))

# extract values
 total$price
# $sso
# [1] 50 50 50

# $spy
# [1] 30 30

 total$price['sso']
# $sso
# [1] 50 50 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you avoid the `list` structure, unless you really need it. Overall, `data.frame` will be much more amenable to analysis (at least for this type of data).

Below an example of converting a similar list into a data.frame. There are certainly shortcuts here, and would love to see the answer from someone more proficient in R, but this should do the trick for now

```
aapl<-list(px=rnorm(10), return=rnorm(10))
ms<-list(px=rnorm(10), return=rnorm(10))

l<-list(aapl,ms) 
names(l)<-c("aapl","ms")
#make each list element a data.frame instead
l<-lapply(l, function(x) as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, x))) 
#now bind those into one big data.frame
l<-do.call(rbind, l)
#finally insert a column with the ticker
l$ticker<-gsub("\\.[0-9]+", "",row.names(l))
```